# Rails 4.2: Rake Task to Import CSV Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv, rake-task

I have a rake task that should import a `.csv` file and save the data into the database. So far it runs but when I check the database - **nothing was saved and I see no errors** - leaving me with no direction.

*I'm using Rails 4.2 with Postgresql for the db.*

Here is my task..

```
namespace :import_users do
  desc "imports user data from a csv file"
      task :data => :environment do
            require 'csv'
              CSV.foreach('/Users/RAILS/Extra Files/2015 User Report.csv') do |row|
                  plan                  = row[0]
                  contact_ident         = row[1]
                  prefer_fax            = row[2]
                  pin                   = row[3] 
                  name                  = row[4] #account
                  first_name            = row[5]
                  last_name             = row[6]
                  email                 = row[7]      
                  phone                 = row[8] 

                  prefer_fax == "Yes" ? p_fax = true : p_fax = false

                  p = Plan.where("name ~ ?","#{plan}( )")

                  user = User.create(   contact_ident: contact_ident, 
                                        prefer_fax: p_fax, 
                                        first_name: first_name, 
                                        last_name: last_name, 
                                        email: email
                                    )

                  account = Account.where("pin ~ ?", "#{pin}").first_or_create do |account|
                              account.name  = name
                              account.phone = phone
                            end

                  user.plans    << p
                  user.accounts << account
            end
      end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to replace

```
User.create
```

with

```
User.create!
```

so if there is any problem with creation it raise.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know the bang did that. It appears that it has to do with my model Validations. I now have direction and can take it from here. Thank you very much!